# Need to read from XML with read only DB access

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to build a process where I can dump a list of IDs to an XML document which can then be used in a SQL statement to return information for only those IDs.  I feel as though I'm very close, but the BFILENAME function I need to use to open the XML file requires that I use the CREATE DIRECTORY statement which fails as I have read-only access and cannot create objects.  Is there something else I can do to be able to create the directory used in the BFILENAME function?

I'm experienced in building SQL statements, but have never had to pull data from an external source in this way.

Here is the script I'm trying to run as a proof-of-concept test.  Ultimately this will be joining into another table and spooling output to a CSV file.

```
CREATE DIRECTORY temp_dir AS 'C:\Users\MyDude\Desktop\'; 

DECLARE

 acct_doc xmltype := xmltype( bfilename('temp_dir','TestXML.xml'), nls_charset_id('AL32UTF8') );
 vis_PersonID varchar(100); 

BEGIN

select PersonID
into vis_PersonID
 from xmltable(
  '/Root/E'
  passing acct_doc
  columns PersonID VARCHAR2(400) PATH '.'
 );

END;
```

This is failing on line 1 as I have read only access.  I have only two IDs in the file, if this were working properly I'd expect to see those two IDs output.

Comment: Creating a directory should be a one-off action, not part of a process you'll re-run; so your DBA could do that and grant privs to your user. That path looks suspiciously like it might be on a client machine; directory objects have to point to an operating system on (or accessible from) the database server.

Comment: you cant select into multiple rows into one scalar variable.